# NSXMLParser parser:didStartElement not triggered when parsing xml

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse xml file and get no errors but when trying to read it, parser:didStartElement event is not triggered. What I am doing wrong? Thanks for help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            // xml connect
            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.test.com/list.xml"];
            NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

            //Start parsing the XML file.
            BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

            if(success)
                NSLog(@"No Errors");
            else
                NSLog(@"Error!");
        }

        // reading xml...

        - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
          namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
            attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"main"]) {
                //Initialize the array.
                apps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }
            else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"prog"]) {

                //Extract the attribute here.
                idUsuari = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Id"];

                NSLog(@"ID: %@", idUser);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't set your view controller as the XML Parser's delegate:

```
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
```

After you alloc / init. Without this the parser does not know who to send the delegate messages to.

Answer (score 0):

declare that your current class conforms to `NSXMLParserDelegate`, then

```
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
```

before you parse, so the parser knows can call the delegate methods implemented by you.

eg

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to Info.plist after run again

[image]